# If $G \cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, then $\mathbb R[G] \cong \mathbb R \times \mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory, group-rings

Let $G = \{1,g,g^2\}$ be the cyclic group of order three. Consider the group ring $\mathbb R[G]$, then $\mathbb R[G] \cong \mathbb R \times \mathbb C$ with the isomorphism
$$
 \varphi(1) = (1,0), \quad
 \varphi(g) = (1,\omega), \quad
 \varphi(g^2) = (1,\overline{\omega})
$$
this is written [in this document](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101bS07/Math101b_notesD.pdf) on page 7. But I am unsure, first
$$
 (1,0)(1,\omega) = (1, 0) \ne (1,\omega)
$$
so $(1,0)$ does not behave like an identity. Further in $\mathbb R[G]$ we have
$(1+g)(1+g) = 1 + 2g + g^2$, but 
$$
((1,0) + (1,\omega))((1,0)+(1,\omega)) = (2,\omega)(2,\omega) = (4,\overline \omega) \ne (1,0) + 2(1,\omega) + (1,\overline \omega)
$$
The first objection might be fixed by setting $\varphi(1) = (1,1)$, but then the second still does not works out.

> So how does this isomorphism work? Or have I used the wrong multiplication, isn't it defined componentwise?

Comment: a ring map can't send $1$ to $(1, 0)$, so something is wrong.

Comment: Note that knowing what $\varphi(g)$ is actually determines the ring homomorphism (assuming $\mathbb R$-linearity), and $\varphi(g)$ must be carried to a primitive cube root of unity. There aren't very many choices in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb C$ for cube roots of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document only says that 
$$\phi(g)=(1, \omega)$$

As you observed you must have 
$$\phi(1)=(1,1)$$

Fixing this, the second relation becomes:

$$((1,1) + (1,\omega))((1,1)+(1,\omega)) = (2,1+\omega)(2,1+\omega) = (4,1+2\omega+\bar{w}) \\
=(1,0) + 2(1,\omega) + (1,\overline \omega)$$

Answer (score 5):

So $\phi$ is defined by $\phi(g) = (1,\omega)$. Hence we must have 
$$ \phi(1) = \phi(g^3) = (1, \omega)^3 = (1,1) $$
(Perhaps $(1,0)$ is a typo). For your second objection, note that $1+g$ mapsto 
$(2, 1+\omega)$, and 
$$ \phi(1 + g)^2 = (2,1+\omega)^2 = (4, 1 + 2\omega + \bar\omega) $$
On the other hand
\begin{align*}
  \phi(1 + 2g + g^2) &= (1, 1) + (2, 2\omega) + (1, \bar\omega)\\
                     &= (4, 1 + 2\omega + \bar\omega)\\
                     &= \phi(1+g)^2
\end{align*}